# Characteristic function of a random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, characteristic-functions

If  $ \phi $ is a Characteristic function of a random variable $X$ , then $\phi^n$ is Characteristic function of which random variable?

Answer (score 1):

Of $X*X*\cdots *X$, where $*$ denotes convolution, and it is taken $n$ times.

Comment: Okkay. Thanks..